# Setting higher upload limit

Tags: uploads, media

How can I change the standard 7MB upload limit?

I have full shell and admin access to my Wordpress blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your .htaccess file in the root of WordPress installation directory:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

and you can change 20 to whatever you want, unless your hosting server is limiting it it should work just fine.

### Update:

Create the php.ini File and add the Following:

```
memory_limit = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 192M
post_max_size = 20M
file_uploads = On
```

then Upload the File to your wp-admin Directory.

Comment: No luck - the limit is still 7MB. BTW, I have full server access (I use a Dreamhost account).

Comment: having a Dreamhost account doesn't mean you have full access! can you change the php.ini file?

Comment: Where is that file located?

Comment: it should be located in your server's php folder, but try the solution i added to the answer

Comment: Added both, still no luck.

Comment: Like i said it should work unless your server is limiting it and guess what? dreamhost have a 7-8 MB upload limit (a simple google search told me that). any why there are way around it for example: http://www.bluesunray.com/2010/06/01/how-to-increase-upload-max-file-size-for-dreamhost/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's probably the time to move on to a VPS.

Answer (score -1):

I installed the wordpress plugin `Tuxedo Big File Uploads`.
Now I have a upload limit of 988 GB.
Using this plugin you don't need to edit php.ini or .htaccess files.
You are even able to disable the plugin later if you want.